# Unexpected behavior of get_environment_variable with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am using a subroutine call to `GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` to read the computer hostname in a Fortran program. I cannot read this variable, though it is okay if I read other variables, as `$USER`. In my system (Debian Jessie, gfortran 4.9):

```
$ echo $HOSTNAME 
deckard
$ echo $USER
curro
```

I have prepared this short program:

```
program hello
!                                           
implicit none
integer :: ivar = 0, len, stat
character(LEN=256) :: host, user
call GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE('HOSTNAME', host, len, stat)
if (stat == 0) then
  print*, "Hostname read: ", host
else
  print*, "Hostname read failed: stat = ", stat
endif
call GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE('USER', user, len, stat)
if (stat == 0) print*, "Username read: ", user
print *, "This is user ", trim(user), " in node ",  trim(host), "." 
!
end program hello
```

If I run this simple program (compiled with or without the -std=f2003) the output is:

```
$ ./a.out 
Hostname read failed: stat =            1
Username read: curro                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
This is user curro in node .
```

Therefore the error is stat = 1. 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 I know that gfortran has the intrinsic `HOSTNM` but for compatibility with other compilers I would prefer `GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Check stat and see what the error message means.

Comment: Values of `stat` 1, -1 and 2 (as well as 0, naturally) have well defined meanings.  You should certainly look at the value.

Comment: Or remove stat and read the error message.

Comment: The stat value after the suroutine call is 1. Removing stat there is no error message whatsoever.

Comment: Value 1 corresponds to the environment variable not existing.  Are you sure it is exported to the environment of the running program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suppose that your shell is bash but the end result should not change too much if the actual shell is another one.

In bash, you have access to [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) and to regular bash variables. To make a variable accessible to child process (that is, programs that are launched by bash such as gfortran or your program 'a.out') it has to be part of the environment. By default, only variables from the [posix set of environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) are passed along (altough some may be omitted).

Examples of posix variables that are accessible both from the bash command line and from your fortran program (or any other program for that matter): `HOME`, `USER`, `PWD` or `PATH`.

You can verify that they are indeed accessible by checking what the `env` program knows:

```
env | grep HOME
env | grep USER
```

while

```
env | grep HOSTNAME
```

returns nothing.

So you need to export the variable HOSTNAME to place it in the list of known environment variable. bash happens to know about hostname because it defines a set of variables for the convenience of the user (see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-HOSTNAME ). Another example of convenience variables is `BASH_VERSION` that is specific to bash itself.

```
export HOSTNAME
env | grep HOSTNAME
```

but the users of your program (or yourself but on a different computer) might not have access to it as an environment variable so this solution might not be of use to you. The "canonical" way of knowing the hostname without relying on the environment variable, on linux, is to execute the program "hostname".

Comment: Thanks, very nice explanation. I thought that HOSTNAME was as valid as environmental variable as USER or HOME but they are different. In fact if I run $ export HOSTNAME; ./a.out I got the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Have you exported the `HOSTNAME` variable?

Exporting means that it is available to the child processes as well. That might very well be the difference between the `HOSTNAME` and `USER` environment variables that you experience.